# Parsing a string separated by commas works only once?

Tags: c

I have a menu when I press 'A' I do the following code which parses the numbers separated by commas.  The first time I press 'A' The results are 100% accurate. But the second+ times I press 'A' from the menu to repeat the same code, I get strange results.  I am using MPLAB C18 Compiler with PIC18

I am using MPLAB C18 Compiler with PIC18

**First Time Output**

> 0002
>
> 0100
>
> 0200
>
> 0100

**Second+ Times Output**

> 0002

**Code**

```
char somestr[] ="2,0100,0200,0100";
char *pt;
int a;
pt = strtokpgmram (somestr,",");

while (pt != NULL) 
{
    a = atoi(pt);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    pt = strtokpgmram (NULL, ",");
}
```

How do you fix it so that every time I press 'A' from the menu I get the same results as first time output?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include your menu logic as well?

Comment: @ErikN, It's just a switch case kind of thing.

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you paste entire code or menu code snippet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because, calling strtok() will change the original string itself. You have to make a copy of the original string before calling strtok().

I made a sample program especially for your understanding.

See, it in the tokenize function, everytime I am making an copy and using the copy.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void tokenize(char* s){

    char *pt;
    int a;

    char* copy_somestr = malloc((strlen(s)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(copy_somestr,s);

    pt = strtok (copy_somestr,",");

    while (pt != NULL)
    {
        a = atoi(pt);
        printf("a = %d somestr = %s\n", a,s);
        pt = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }

    free(copy_somestr);
}
void main(){
    char somestr[] ="2,0100,0200,0100";

     /*
    printf("Beginning somestr = %s",somestr);
    // If you tokenize here without making any copy using somestr, It still works well But after this call somestr will become unusable.
    printf("Afterlast somestr = %s",somestr);
    */


    tokenize(somestr);

     // You could still use somestr
    printf("I could still use somestr = %s\n",somestr);


    tokenize(somestr);  

}
```

Comment: @Ammar  Is this your full code? could you paste your calling function in detail.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT, Can you please show me the code I would need to add as part of your answer? It sounds logical.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT .. how do you make a copy of the original string? If you can show the final whole code that would be the answer to my question.

Comment: I used strcpy(somestr, somestr2) to copy original string 'somestr2' to somestr. This way I don't lose my original string.

Comment: @Ammar No using strcpy will not make you to lose the original string.