# Why does this use of strtok() cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, strtok

I am trying to get ALL tokens in a string using `strtok()` and convert them to integers.  After getting one token, trying to pull another promptly segfaults - how do I tell the system that this is not a segfault condition so it can complete?

Code:

```
char * token;
while ( getline (file,line) )
{
  char * charstarline = const_cast<char*>(line.c_str()); //cast to charstar
  char * token;
  token = strtok(charstarline," ");
        token = strtok(charstarline," ");
  int inttoken = atoi(token);
  cout << "Int token: " << inttoken << endl;
  while (token != NULL)
  {
token = strtok (NULL, " ");
int inttoken = atoi(token);
cout << "Int token (loop): " << inttoken << endl;
  }
```

Is casting away const why it segfaults?  If so how do I get around this?

Comment: Why are you const-casting away the const-ness of `line.c_str()`? Also, the tags are working fine, you shouldn't have two different tags for one idea.

Comment: because strtok gives a compiler error if I feed it a const char *; it asks for a char * so i casted out the const part

Comment: @Xymostech `strtok` takes a `char*`, not a `const char*`, so it's required to shoot yourself in the foot if you're directly parsing a std::string using `strtok`. Doing an `strdup` would be better.

Comment: shoot yourself in the foot? what is wrong with having it be non-const?  I don't actually change it so it should work ok - is there some reason this doesn't work with a non-const, or that I need a const?  COnfused here, jst trying to extract the tokens, don't care if the string gets clobbered once I have the tokens out of it (trying to save them as ints, eventually into an array, though that is not implemented yet)

Comment: @user2333388 strtok modifies the string it parses. It'll probably work, not saying it won't, but one should always at least take a deep breath before casting away const :)

Comment: so casting it to non-const should be good right?  its ok if it modifies or destroys the string so long as I get my ints out of it first.

Comment: what I don't get is why this segfaults after reading one int from a line (it didn't fault until I added the small while NOT NULL loop, but I only got the first token from each line without it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` discussion aside, this is probably your real problem;

```c
while (token != NULL)                // Up to the last token, is not NULL
{
  token = strtok (NULL, " ");        // No more tokens makes it go NULL here
  int inttoken = atoi(token);        // and we use the NULL right away *boom*
                                     // before checking the pointer.
  cout << "Int token (loop): " << inttoken << endl;
}
```

Comment: while (token != NULL)
  {
    token = strtok (NULL, " ");
    if(token != NULL)
    {
    int inttoken = atoi(token);
    cout << "Int token (loop): " << inttoken << endl;
    }
  }

Comment: and it fixed the segfault, but now it only gets one token per line again! (there are 5 ints on each line, separated by spaces, in my test textfile)

Comment: @user2333388 Its because you have to copy the string before using that. Else it will create problems. see this link  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345707/parsing-a-string-separated-by-commas-works-only-once/16345832#16345832

Comment: @user2333388 Your problem may come from calling `token = strtok(charstarline," ");` twice in a row, the first will modify (null terminate) the string after the first token, which confuses the second call the line right after.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
char *  charstarline = malloc(sizeof(char)+1 * line.c_str() )
```

Because it will allocate new space.

But,

`char * charstarline = const_cast<char*>(line.c_str());`, will not allocate new space.

I came to this conclusion, by executing the below example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){

   char  charstarline[] = "hello abc def how\0"; //cast to charstar
   //here char * charstarline = "hello abc def how\0" is not working!!!!!

   char * token;
   token = strtok(charstarline," ");

   //int inttoken = atoi(token);
   //cout << "Int token: " << inttoken << endl;
   while (token != NULL)
   {
          token = strtok (NULL, " ");
          //int inttoken = atoi(token);
          cout << "Int token (loop): " << token << endl;
    }
 }
```